# Should I remove events before changing a div content?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks

I've inherited a jQuery application that does its work by calling AJAX services without leaving the page.

There is a list of items, where when you click on an item the detail of the item is displayed, events attached to the buttons, then the html is disposed and new html will be created, new events attached and so on and so forth.

I was wondering whether JavaScript garbage collection will automatically clean up those events, or do they go in some Map like data structure and create a memory leak.  Am I supposed to clean them up explicitly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you always bind the same events, you could also use something like jQuery live() or the likes instead of always binding/unbinding them.

Comment: interesting, so you're saying that with live() I attach it once at document.ready() and jQuery will take care of bind/unbind for me. Will it work even if the element doesn't exist yet when I call live?

Comment: What live() does is that it binds event to the body tag instead of the actual element, and then check if the event target matches your selector when it bubbles up to the body tag. That way, your element does't have to exist at the time you bind your events.

Comment: and I've [already experimented and it works](http://jsfiddle.net/BLNLV/2/), thank you, interesting also to know the implementation trick that you've mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript garbage collection will *not* remove bound events to removed elements. jQuery functions often *do* depending on what method you use.

In example, `.html()` or `.remove()` will remove events and not leak memory. When in doubt you can always use `.empty()`.

---

In my opinion the `.live()` discussion is fairly beside the point of memory leaks. The usage of `.live()` should be done when it makes sense from an architecture standpoint. Unless you need the event to be bound *before* the element is added to the DOM, or exist *after* the element is removed (because it may be added again) then `.bind()` is really the proper and faster method to use. `.live()` is slower than `.bind()` because each event must fire at the element, bubble to the `document` and then bubble back up to the element in order to be processed by `.live()`, while with `.bind` it can execute right away.

Also, FYI both `.bind()` and `.live()` are deprecated in the newest version of jQuery (1.7). They will still function, but the new syntax is `.on()`, using delegation to replace `.live()`. This is because too much `.live()` really slows down pages because each `.live` binds another event to the `document` which must be listened and processed every single event.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to make it easier on the GC and not make him search if it has references , so you should unbind / die all events to the div.

Comment: Ok, so you say just to make it easier, there is not a leak issue. I can do that nonetheless. With jquery I bind a click event as $('selector').click(). How to unbind?

Comment: $('selector').click() is an alias for $('selector').bind('click',function () {});  so  : $('selector').unbind('click');